# Java HTTP GET response waits until timeout

Tags: java, http, tcp, timeout

I am supposed to develop a program that reads a web page with the specified URL, but the problem is that I am not allowed to use any HTTP libraries, I am only allowed to use TCP.

Below is the code that reads the response message:

```
private static String readMultiline (BufferedReader inStr) {
    String message="";
    String line=readLine(inStr);

    while (line != null) {
         message += line + "\r\n";
         line=readLine(inStr);
    }

    if (message.length() == 0) return null;
        return message;
}

private static String readLine (BufferedReader inStr) {
    String line = null;
    try{
         line = inStr.readLine();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
         System.out.println("ERROR: Incoming packet could not be read properly.");
         return null;
    }
    return line;
}
```

The problem is that the header and the web page content are completely received, but the while loop still waits for the 'next' line, which does not exist. After a while, timeout occurs and the code continues. The server I am trying to connect to does not do "Connection:close". How can I detect the end of the file?

Comment: Is this homework? Why would you be banned from using the HTTP libraries that are included in the Java SDK?

Comment: Yes, it is a homework. Although, as far as I can see, HTTP libraries work pretty much the same way when it comes to reading from the stream. As far as it cannot detect the end of the file, the problem will occur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other answers were deleted so I will post one up. You are using an IO method that read *lines* of information, with a line being defined as a set of characters terminated by a newline character. But there is no guarantee that your TCP packets are ending in newline, so you need to use a more agnostic IO read to process them.

Take a look at DataInputStream, it has a convenience method called `readFully` that I think you will find quite helpful.

Comment: Wow I didn't know about readFully(), that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 0):

read up on the HTTP protocol.  look for length information.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to parse the header and use BufferedReader.read() instead of readLine().

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the late answer.

For anyone who might have suffered the same problem, I also forgot to add "Connection: close" line **to the request itself**. When I added it, timeout problem disappeared. With this and read()/readFully() functions, I managed to solve the problem. Hope it helps anyone.